# Shell | syntax error near unexpected token `(' before for loop

Tags: shell

I have following code snippet in shell :

```
Count=10;
for  ( i=1 ; i<=$Count ; i++ )
do
#Some Operations                
done
```

while running the above code, it is giving following error

```
123: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
123: line 2: `for  ( i=1 ; i<=$Count ; i++ )'
```

This code was working fine, but suddenly it started giving this error.
Tried many things but it is not working.

Comment: I think you mean `for (( i=1; i<=$Count; i++))`.

Comment: Specify which shell you're using.

Comment: In addition to the need for double parentheses, do not use `/bin/sh`, use `/bin/bash` or `/bin/ksh`

Comment: `123` appears to be the name of the program executing your script. It's unclear what that is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double parenthesis:

```
Count=10;
for (( i=1 ; i<=$Count ; i++ ))
do
 echo $i
done
```